# Speed comparison: add zero or check non-zero first

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm optimizing the most time-consuming loop in a program I'm writing that sums many entries in an array, many of which will be zero. Is if faster to check if an entry is zero before adding it, or skip the check and add all entries? Examples of each below. This is in C++. Thanks!

```
double *arr, sum=0;
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum += arr[i];
```

OR

```
double *arr, sum=0;
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arr[i])
        sum += arr[i];
```

Comment: Profile, don't guess.

Comment: Clearly a check for a value and an if are going to take more time than a simple addition, but it's highly unlikely that either of them has any sort of impact on your code. What makes you think that this will make any difference at all? Do you have profiler output that indicates this code is a bottleneck?

Comment: And when you profile and measure, do it with optimization enabled when building.

Comment: What's the probability that `arr[i] == 0`? If it's low then it's clear that your first code will be faster.

Comment: The first version is definitely faster (or, at least, not slower) on current x86/arm cpus. No need to guess/profile here. Even, the compiler should remove the `if` from the second version, if `-ffast-math` or equivalent is specified (too bad, that none of gcc/clang/icc/msvc does it).

Comment: Because `sum` is a local variable and not aliased, there's no performance benefit to avoiding an occasional extra assignment.  If it were potentially aliased, or even inside a structure with other data in the same cache line potentially shared between threads, things could change quite significantly.

Answer (score 3):

**Quote of the day:**

> ***Premature optimization is the root of all evil***
>   - Donald Knuth

If your intent is to add all the elements of an array, then write the code that does exactly this and let the compiler's optimizer take care of what's best.  So go for the first alternative; your future you will be thankful one day.

**Don't do manual optimizations if not absolutely necessary:**

With modern CPU, it's anyway difficult to think of all the possible effects of cache management, cache optimisation, jump prediction, and other hardware tricks.  The compiler's optimizer can combine much more factors than we can.

If you really notice some performance issues, then **profile your code, and concentrate your efforts on optimizations that really matter**.  Alternatively, you could benchmark the code on your target platform, but beware of subtle differences in the benchmark, that might affect the optimizer.

Now, this being said, the second option requires a compare instruction (`ucomisd` on x86) for every item in the array.  So if most of the items have a non zero value, you mostly add an unnecessary overhead. For null items you'd have exchanged a simple add with two instructions, a compare and a conditional branch. I'm not sure if this is really faster, but if there would be any benefit, it would very probably be extremely marginal. So in the best case you achieve a very marginal gain, but most probably you'll add some overhead.  So intuitively, stick to the first alternative, unless your profiler tells you there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did profile my code, and found that this loop is the one that really matters, hence the optimization. Surprisingly it looks like there is a difference, see my answer below.

Comment: Just wanted to double check one more thing before posting, it's up now.

Comment: @wcroughan No problem - I've done an **informa**l benchmark (here: https://ideone.com/6DXdVH ), and it appears clearly in favor of alternative 1. The difference of execution time depends on the density of 0.0 in the array (with only a couple of non null values, timing is almost equal, a very little better for alt 1.  With more than 50% of non zero values, alternative 1 is an order of magnitude faster.  But if you want you can test with your compiler to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on Intel architecture, there is one way you could speed this up, but it's not pretty: you use the `REPZ SCASD` instruction to scan your array for the next non-zero element. You will need to program this in assembly language, of course. And it relies on most of the zero elements of the array being represented as `0x0000000000000000`, which although probably true is not guaranteed.

If I were implementing this, I would write a C-callable function in assembly language:

```
size_t NextNonZeroArrayElement (double* arr, size_t len)
```

This will only be worth it if *most* of the elements are zero (not just if *many* of them are zero). But in any case it's a fun project if you have the time for it.

If you are really enthusiastic, you might consider writing the whole thing in assembly language, complete with floating-point operations. Then I think you would come out ahead at a much lower proportion of zero elements.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into it!

Comment: `REPx SCASD` isn't even that fast

Comment: Using SIMD would be much better

Answer (score 2):

For modern CPUs (assuming a "non-negligable" array size); the fastest option will be to use SIMD. For example, maybe a small "start loop" that does individual elements of the array until any alignment requirements are met, then a "middle loop" that uses AVX2 (where a group of 8 `int` additions can be done in parallel by a single instruction), then maybe a small "end loop" that does any final elements of the array that weren't enough to be a group of 8. For the small loops (at start/end) unpredictable branches are nasty and can cost 10 times more than a simple addition, but predictable branches are nice, so it depends on how predictable the occurrences of zeros is.

Of course for extremely large arrays you'd also want to use multiple CPUs - e.g. with a "low-end" 4-core chip (and SIMD) you might split the array into quarters and do 4*8 integer additions in parallel.

For a perfect compiler, it wouldn't make any difference what you wrote in the C source code - the resulting assembly would be the same "fastest option for the CPU/s using SIMD" code.

Beyond that it comes down to how much your compiler fails to be perfect. Most compilers can't auto-vectorize. Most compilers won't realize that `if(x) sum += x;` is equivalent to `sum += x;`. No compilers will create threads for you. You need to profile to determine why your compiler failed, then spend extra time to rewrite the code (with threads and intrinsics) because you should've "prematurely foreseen" that the compiler sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. For those who found this question and are doing something similar, I ran some profiling and found that the two have essentially identical runtimes.

I built with optimizations on and ran on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Also for further optimization:
Interestingly, if the inside operation is more intensive, as below, adding the if statement reduces runtime by almost half. Also, if you have one indicator variable that you check and one that you add, then adding the if statement roughly doubles runtime, presumably due to double the memory movement. Both of these had 10% nonzero entries in the two arrays.

Faster with if statement:

```
double *arr, sum=0;
int *arri;
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arri[i])
        sum += arr[i] * arri[i];
```

Faster without if statement (assumes arri[i] == 0 implies arr[i] == 0):

```
double *arr, sum=0;
int *arri;
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arri[i])
        sum += arr[i];
```

Comment: What is `arri`? it wasn't in the question

Comment: It's just another variable I added to test out the effects of formulating the sum in different ways. The array from the original question was precomputed, but here the elements involve a product. Just wanted to give some useful benchmarks for problems that could, for instance, benefit from some precomputation.